# Required attribute with tag select doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I tried with required="true" and with th:required="required" and using only required(this throws an error since i am using thymeleaf), added the empty value value="",but still doesn't work.I tried added value="dumb" and value="" for the second option tag, same...doesn't work and tried using bootstrap validator.When I submit the form I have an pop-up, if I press OK then form is submitted.
I am using chrome and I have another form where I am using input + required and there it's working.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<form th:action="@{/appointment/create}" method="post" id="appointmentForm">
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="location">Alege institutia:</label>

                <select class="form-control" required="required" 
                th:value="${appointment.institutie}"name="institutie" 
                id="institutie">

                 <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" > 
                 -- alege institutia --</option>
                 <option th:each="institutie : ${institutieList}"  
               th:text="${institutie.numeInstitutie}" ></option>

               </select>
</div></form>


            var confirm = function() {
            bootbox.confirm({
                title : "Confirmare programare",
                message : "Doriti sa creeati programarea?",
                buttons : {
                    cancel : {
                        label : '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Nu'
                    },
                    confirm : {
                        label : '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Da'
                    }
                },
                callback : function(result) {
                    if (result == true) {
                        $('#appointmentForm').submit();
                    } else {
                        console.log("Confirmare anulata.");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

UPDATE 
The controller which takes care to populate the "institutieList"

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createAppointmentPost(Model model, @ModelAttribute("city") 
City city, @ModelAttribute("agency") Agency agency, Principal principal){

    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    Appointment appointment=new Appointment();
    model.addAttribute("appointment", appointment);
    model.addAttribute("dateString", "");
    model.addAttribute("cities", cityService.findAll());    
    model.addAttribute("institutieList", instituteService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("myFiles", userService.listAllUploadedFiles(user));
    return "appointment";
}
```

UPDATE 2:
The problem was with the submit button, I've forgot type="submit".

Comment: you set the first option as selected="selected". Then your Value is required but its already set to this value. Why is your first option disabled  and selected ?

Comment: disabled because i don't want to be able to choose it and selected, because I want to show it first. It's like the first option is "Choose". If i don't use selected, the dropdown will show the fist value from DB.

Comment: Ok i tryed this (without Thymeleaf) and its working properly. I cannot submit the Form if this value is not set (Im not familiar with Thymeleaf).

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why is not working with thymeleaf. With the tag input is working,I though it has something to do with that pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage for required isn't required="true" but only required, like so:

```
<select class="form-control" required 
            th:value="${appointment.institutie}"name="institutie" 
            id="institutie">
```

Comment: Why the downvote if I may ask? See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

Comment: Using Thymeleaf is required="required" as far as I know. If I use required as you suggested, will throw an error.

Comment: What error? Using required="required" won't do anything with Thymeleaf as it doesn't start with th:. I'm using plain required in my forms and it works for me.

Comment: This error: ERROR 7616 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.thymeleaf.templateparser.ErrorHandler  : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8181-exec-3] Fatal error during parsing

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "required" associated with an element type "select" must be followed by the ' = ' character. I didn't downvote you, but your comment is not usefull. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well that's strange. I'll look at it tomorrow when I have access to my code again and post a working sample.

Comment: <select id="type" th:field="*{exampleEnum}" class="form-control" required>
        <option th:each="type : ${T(com.n4zroth.ExampleEnum).values()}"
                     th:value="${#strings.toUpperCase(type)}"
                     th:text="${type.value}">Type
        </option>
</select> is working fine for me :( Which version of Thymeleaf are you using?

Comment: Using `required="required"` is what is suggested here [1] and works for me. 
[1] http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-required-quot-required-quot-isn-t-working-td4026979.html